# Is it possible to get the content of a script file in a database project?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd, database-project

Ok so I have a Visual Studio Database project where I´m trying to do some **post deployment stuff** (Script.PostDeployment.sql).

## What am I trying to do?

What I like to do is to be able to **copy the content of a script file and insert it into a procedure**.

### Overview

So I have a file with some SQLCMD

```
MyScriptFileWithSomeInserts.sql -- The content I like to log is in this file

exec InsertDataProcedure [ScriptContent] -- How can I get it here?
```

Here we have some **pseudocode** of what I'm trying to do

```
-- read file and insert to variable
:setvar ScriptContent :r MyScriptFileWithSomeInserts.sql 

-- input the content to the procedure
exec InsertDataProcedure [@ScriptContent]
```

## What have I tried?

### 1

The following fails because this is **not** a procedure but just a script in my database project.

```
declare @ScriptContent nvarchar(Max)
SELECT @ScriptContent = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'MyScriptFileWithSomeInserts.sql'))
exec InsertDataProcedure @ScriptContent
```

### 2

I have tried to use **:r** ([SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017)) to read the file

```
declare @xx nvarchar(Max) =
:r MyScriptFileWithSomeInserts.sql

exec InsertDataProcedure [@ScriptContent]
```

### 3

I have tried to use all kinds of variations of [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017) like e.g **:i** to read the file

```
declare @xx nvarchar(Max) =
:i MyScriptFileWithSomeInserts.sql

exec InsertDataProcedure [@ScriptContent]
```

#### My setup

Visual Studio 2019 and target platform MS Azure SQL Database V12.

## Update: How this was solved

This is what I ended up with after the help from John.

```
DECLARE @solutionDir VARCHAR(200),@File VARCHAR(200)
-- In the SQLCMD I have access to $(SolutionPath) so I need to do some 
-- cleaningto get the absolute path to the file
SELECT @solutionDir = REPLACE('$(SolutionPath)','MySolution.sln','');
SET @File = @solutionDir + 'Databases\MyDb\MyScriptFileWithSomeInserts.sql'
        
DECLARE @retvalue nvarchar(max)  
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ParmDef nvarchar(50);

-- Read the content of the file
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @File + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x' ;   
SET @ParmDef = N'@retvalOUT nvarchar(max) OUTPUT';
 
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDef, @retvalOUT=@retvalue OUTPUT;

-- And here I have all the content of the file.
PRINT '@retvalue: ' + @retvalue
```

Comment: `sp_executesql`. And don't confuse SQLCMD variables with TSQL variables. Not the same thing.

Comment: I forgot to note that I did try to use sp_executesql without success. Could you show me what you had in mind?

Comment: I only had a second to skim that. So if you're able to run from SQLCMD then why not just `:r MyScriptFileWithSomeInserts.sql` followed by `GO`?

Comment: See my try nr 2 where I use :r. Im trying to send all the content of the file into the procedure where I save it to table. This is a auditing move. So I have been trying to use :r in every manner thinkable (to me at least). Please let me know if you got this for me, that would be awesome!

Comment: Well if you need to bring it in as a string and pass it into a stored procedure for auditing that changes things. Do you have any control over how this insert batch is created? How long it is?

Comment: Ill add to my answer tomorrow when Im into work again. But it can  be very very  long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but I didn't see OPENROWSET in your list

```
Declare @S varchar(max); 
Select @S = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\SomeDir\SomeScript.sql', SINGLE_BLOB) x; 


Print @S
--Exec(@S)
```

Comment: Going to try this out tomorrow (night here atm)!

Comment: Ok this works if I put the absolute path to the file. Now I just need to find out how I get the relative path to the file compared to the project. I don´t want to hardcode 'C:\Dev\ProjectName\DatabaseProject\Data\Inserts\SomeScript.sql'. Any idea how to do this? $(SolutionDir)  would be great but that doesn´t seem to work.

Comment: @Sturla you would have to wrap the entire thing in Dynamic SQL.  This means you would have dynamic SQL within dynamic SQL.  A little messy in my opinion.   I'll noodle it a bit more.

Comment: hi @John I cobbled together a dynamic version of your answer but I have some syntax error  I'm not spotting. Could you take a look at it for me? I'll then grant you the correct answer because you got me on the right track (90% of the way).

Comment: @Sturla  You set (at)SQL to nvarchar(50) rather than nvarchar(max)   it is being truncated.

Comment: Damn.. that was super silly of me! Now fixed and everything works like a charm! Thank you again

Comment: @Sturla It is always the silly things that we skip right over.  Happy it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Goto database then right click on the table you want the script of and click on "script table as", it shows another section showing "create to" click on that and it opens into another section then select "new query editor window" click on that and your query shows up copy it and paste where ever needed.
right click on table----> script table as-----> create to----> new query editor window
Actually i didnt get your explanation correctly. i just showed you how to get script to copy from one place to another

Comment: Thanks but this is a Visual Studio database project where I condittionslly (with SQLCMD) run the scripts. They are *.sql files but will on my case only contain insert/update/delete of data. But I want to log these actions into the database by (somehow) reading the script file and sending the content into the logging proceidure.